# Confusion about a equation in a paper

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, random, covariance

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.04667.pdf), in proposition 2, the covariance matrix of the periodogram estimator is computed for the Gaussian process. However, at the end of proof says  "upon substituting (52) and (54) into (51), the results follows". I do not know how they obtain that result **Eq. (15)**.

May someone elaborate on this derivation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting the summation in $(51)$ into the terms where $r\neq r'$ and those where $r=r'$ gives that 
\begin{align*}
\Sigma_{pg}&=\mathbb E[\hat{p}_{pg}\hat{p}_{pg}^H]-pp^H\\&=\frac1{R^2}\sum_{r=1,r'=1}^R\mathbb E[\text{diag}(V^Hx_rx_r^HV)\text{diag}(V^Hx_rx_r^HV)^H]-pp^H\\&=\frac{1}{R^2}\left(\sum_{r\neq r'}\mathbb E[\text{diag}(V^Hx_rx_r^HV)\text{diag}(V^Hx_rx_r^HV)^H]+\sum_{r=r'}\mathbb E[\text{diag}(V^Hx_rx_r^HV)\text{diag}(V^Hx_rx_r^HV)^H]\right)-pp^H\\&=\frac1{R^2}\left(\sum_{r\neq r'}pp^H+\sum_{r=r'}2(\text{diag}^2(p)+pp^H)\right)-pp^H\\&=\frac1{R^2}\left((R^2-R)pp^H+R(2\text{diag}^2(p)+pp^H)\right)-pp^H\\&=\frac2R\text{diag}^2(p),
\end{align*}
which is exactly $(15)$.